# Pyinstaller Fatal Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've converted my script (rsa2.py) to exe with pyinstaller but it gives me this Fatal Error

[image]

I've tried this:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onedir --hidden-import FileDialog --debug --noupx rsa2.py
```

Is there any other solution for this error?

Edit: the console says WARNING lib is not found. And most of libs which I've used looks not found when trying to convert py to exe

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong) can be helpful when dealing with pyinstaller problems